# My image is Not Appear Codeigniter

Tags: database, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

[image: my screenshot]

Help my image can't show in my website, can anyone help me?

```html
<div class="row">
    <ul class="portfolio-list lightbox m-none" data-plugin-options="{'delegate': 'a.lightbox-portfolio', 'type': 'image', 'gallery': {'enabled': true}}">
      <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="portfolio-item">
          <span class="thumb-info thumb-info-lighten thumb-info-centered-icons">
            <span class="thumb-info-wrapper">
              <img src="<?php echo $row1['alamat_galeri']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width:100%">
              <span class="thumb-info-action">
                <a href="<?php echo $row1['alamat_galeri']; ?>" class="lightbox-portfolio">
                  <span class="thumb-info-action-icon thumb-info-action-icon-light"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></span>
                </a>
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Comment: set your full image path to directory not only name

Comment: should be like tthis :  `<img src="<?=site_url('path_to_folder/'.$row1['alamat_galeri']); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width:100%">`

Comment: just add a leading slash '/'

Comment: @Rohmat  pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Should be like this :**

Add `site_url()` or `base_url()` with `src` attr

***Note*** : make sure your image path is correct

```
<img src="<?=site_url($row1['alamat_galeri']);?>" 
    class="img-responsive" 
    style="width:100%" >
```

Use below code  if u have your image in folder `galeri`*/

```
<img src="<?=site_url('galeri'.$row1['alamat_galeri']);?>" 
class="img-responsive" 
style="width:100%" >
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: Thanks for helping